# How do you do real time render updates?

Tags: rendering

My scene renders through a compositor, although I have some idea of the final result because the compositor does match it with my scene a little bit, it's not accurate to the image generated.

What I want to do is have my rendered image change every time I do an update without me pressing render images all the time.  I know this is possible because when I update compositor nodes, the image refreshes automatically...

It's complicated to explain, but the easy solution of simply looking at my scene will not help.  I need to look at final rendered image.

Comment: Hello :). Compositor updates after you change any node. What else do you want updated in real time?

Comment: i think she wants an update everytime - whatever she changes. e.g. a color change, or moving objects around and so on.

Comment: Hello Chris, Correct.  The image updates upon any meddling I have with it's nodes.  However if I make simple changes to my scene objects, it will not refresh.

Comment: @JimmyLin that makes sense. The compositor detects automatically all the changes made in your compositing setup but your 3D scene is not part of the compositing setup, it outputs an image which is then read by the Render Layer node in the compositor so unless you change that image (by doing a new render for example), you won't see any changes in the compositor. If I understood correctly, what you are asking is impossible unless you consider doing some scripting.